# Error when installing "ya2yaml" gem on Windows7, Ruby1.9.2, Rails3

Tags: windows-7, yaml, ruby-1.9.2, ruby-on-rails-3

```
Installing ya2yaml (0.30) c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:371:in `rescue in block in initialize_copy': ya2yaml-0.30 has
an invalid value for @cert_chain (Gem::FormatException)
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:364:in `block in initialize_copy'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:360:in `each'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:360:in `initialize_copy'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:638:in `initialize_dup'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:638:in `dup'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:638:in `for_cache'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:746:in `to_ruby_for_cache'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:234:in `write_spec'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:175:in `install'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/source.rb:96:in `install'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/installer.rb:55:in `block in run'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `block in each'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in `run'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/cli.rb:226:in `install'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.11/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/Ruby192/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
        from c:/Ruby192/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
```

I tried to install it like this:

```
$ gem install ya2yaml --platform=ruby
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FormatException)
    ya2yaml-0.30 has an invalid value for @cert_chain
```

But i got another error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update gem

```
gem update --system
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess this should solve your problem

[Error when installing "ya2yaml" gem on Windows7, Ruby1.9.2, Rails3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530847/error-when-installing-ya2yaml-gem-on-windows7-ruby1-9-2-rails3)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your recusive link is causing stack overflows everywhere